# Crontab not firing python script

Tags: python, cron

`crontab -e -u luke`

```
0 5 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/luke/evernote_ticklerfile/main.py >> /home/luke/evernote_ticklerfile/output.txt 2>> /home/luke/evernote_ticklerfile/error.txt
```

This cron never executes. Could it have something to do with python? A bash script will seem to execute perfectly fine.

Comment: So `output.txt`, `error.txt` and cron logs are all empty?

Comment: Did you run exactly that command in a terminal, not a bash script.

Comment: @makozaki yes. Joe Yes, if I run it in the terminal then it works fine